# Retrofit handling empty Jsonarray

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I have retrofit built up like this :

```
public static Retrofit getClient(MCrypt mCrypt) throws Exception {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient;


        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

            okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .readTimeout(90000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .connectTimeout(90000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .build();
        } else {
            okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .readTimeout(90000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .connectTimeout(90000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .build();
        }


        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting()
                .registerTypeAdapter(FeedbackDetails.class,
                        new FeedbackDetailsDeserializer())
                .create();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(mCrypt.decrypt(host_name))
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                // TODO: 14-02-2018 change httpclient to previous
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}

public static class FeedbackDetailsDeserializer
        implements JsonDeserializer<FeedbackDetails> {

    private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    @Override
    public FeedbackDetails deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                                       JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {

        if (json.isJsonArray()) return null;
        return gson.fromJson(json, typeOfT);
    }

}
```

This is how I Parse the data using Gson

```
private void parseResponse(String data) {

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(sendbackActivity.mCrypt.decrypt(data));

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            MainLeadData mainLeadData = new Gson().fromJson(object.toString(), MainLeadData.class);
            sendbackActivity.leadDataArrayList.add(mainLeadData);
        }
        Utility.printMessage("lead arraylist size ..." + sendbackActivity.leadDataArrayList.size());

        setAdapter();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My actual response when there is data :

```
  "feedback_details":{
"id":"79",
"lead_id":"86075",
"account_id":"1543",
"document_id":"582346",
"reason_id":"2",
"description":"Aadhar Card ",
"sales_remark":null,
"lat":"",
"long":"",
"status":"2",
"created_at":"2018-02-27 12:29:59",
"updated_at":"2018-02-27 12:29:59"
}
```

But actually when there is no data in feedback details the response is :

```
    "feedback_details":[
]
```

And Feedback Details Class :

```
public class FeedbackDetails {

    @SerializedName("sales_remark")
    private String salesRemark;

    @SerializedName("account_id")
    private String accountId;

    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    private String updatedAt;

    @SerializedName("description")
    private String description;

    @SerializedName("created_at")
    private String createdAt;

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("document_id")
    private String documentId;

    @SerializedName("lead_id")
    private String leadId;

    @SerializedName("lat")
    private String lat;

    @SerializedName("long")
    private String longitude;

    @SerializedName("reason_id")
    private String reasonId;

    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;

    public void setSalesRemark(String salesRemark) {
        this.salesRemark = salesRemark;
    }

    public String getSalesRemark() {
        return salesRemark;
    }

    public void setAccountId(String accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    public String getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public String getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setDocumentId(String documentId) {
        this.documentId = documentId;
    }

    public String getDocumentId() {
        return documentId;
    }

    public void setLeadId(String leadId) {
        this.leadId = leadId;
    }

    public String getLeadId() {
        return leadId;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setJsonMemberLong(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getJsonMemberLong() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setReasonId(String reasonId) {
        this.reasonId = reasonId;
    }

    public String getReasonId() {
        return reasonId;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

In Retrofit while parsing the response using Gson I am getting this error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2889 path $.applicantDocumentPhotos[0].feedback_details
```

I have used Gson Converter. How can I fix it?

Comment: can i see your code?

Comment: So do you get only an empty array `[]` if there is no actual data and if there is actual data you get a single object? And this is the whole JSON, the root?

Comment: Can you yet check your Json in question? Does it lack some curly braces `{` & `}`? AND add the java  class for `FeedbackDetails`?

Comment: @pirho there is no curly brace missing, and the question is updated with Feedback details class

Comment: Ok, but just to confirm:  your Object response comes without leading `{`? It ends with `}}`. And Array response comes without enclosing `{` & `}`? AND what is `Call<?>`, is it `Call<FeedbackDetails>`?

Comment: Just ignore the last } i have updated it in question, and FeedbackDetails is the class where i will store the data got from feedback_details object

Comment: In your error: `applicantDocumentPhotos` suggests that Json in your question is not necessarily the whole response. So what are you getting and what are you `Call<?>`ing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the type of the object before letting Gson to parse it. If it is an array you might want to return just a `null` value.

Easiest way to do it would be to implement custom `JsonDeserializer`, like:

```
public class FeedbackDetailsDeserializer
            implements  JsonDeserializer<FeedbackDetails> {

    private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    @Override
    public FeedbackDetails deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
            JsonDeserializationContext context)
                throws JsonParseException {

        if(json.isJsonArray()) return null;
        return gson.fromJson(json, typeOfT);
    }

}
```

and register it with the Gson before setting to Retrofit:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting()
    .registerTypeAdapter(FeedbackDetails.class,
            new FeedbackDetailsDeserializer())
    .create();
```

Note also that if your response is like (there are the enclosing `{` & `}` ):

```
{
    "feedback_details":[
    ]
}
```

you need a wrapper class, like:

```
public class FeedbackDetailsResponse {
    public FeedbackDetails feedback_details;
}
```

and your Retrofit service API would have something like:

```
Call<FeedbackDetailsResponse> ...
```

Comment: Got an error? If, what is it? Can you parse the non-array response?

Comment: it is the same error @pirho which is stated in above question

Comment: How do you build the Retrofit? Adding this Gson with TypeAdapter as converter? And you can parse the object response ok? Add the feedback details java class to your question also.

Comment: I have updated my question with your solution please tell me if wrong

Answer (score 0):

this problem from server side response. when data is available then they send object and when data is empty they sends array.  and you need to told to your server side programmer to send object when data is empty.like this  "feedback_details":{} instead  of "feedback_details":[]and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Might this below statement helps you!

**The JSONObject type is from org.json.* not Gson. You want JsonObject from com.google.gson.*, or to bind to your own model class.**